# Running two scripts as one script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've made a little chat program what works within a LAN, if File and Printer sharing is on. It is based on simple plain text files. There are two different scripts. One handles the sending part and the other, receiving part. I've tried to put it as one script but then one must enter a message to receive the one which the other user has sent. So, how do I put it as one script?

The sending script:

```
from sys import exit

LAN_NAME = "\\\\ONE-PC"
LAN_MSG_FILE = "%s\\Users\\Public\\me.txt" % LAN_NAME
TCHAT_VER = "1.1.0"

print "TChat - Version %s" % TCHAT_VER
print "Copyright(c) 2013 - Ahnaf Tahmid"
print "--------------------------------"

def send_data(src, msg):
    _file_ = open(src, 'w')
    _file_.truncate()
    _file_.write(msg)
    _file_.close()

msg = raw_input("[You]: ")
print "\n"

while True:
    send_data(LAN_MSG_FILE, msg)
    msg = raw_input("[You]: ")
    print "\n"
    if msg == "[exit]":
        send_data(LAN_MSG_FILE, "[exit]")

raw_input("Press ENTER to exit.")
exit(0)
```

The recieving script:

```
from sys import exit

CLN = "\\\\TWO-PC"
CLN_MSG_FILE = "%s\\Users\\Public\\me.txt" % CLN
VER = "1.0.0"

def fetch_data(src):
    _file_ = open(src, 'r')
    message = _file_.read()
    _file_.close()
    return message

msg = " "
msg_to_display = "x"

print "TChat Receiver v%s." % VER
print "Copyright(c) 2013 - Ahnaf Tahmid."
print "---------------------------------"
print "\n"

while True:
    msg = fetch_data(CLN_MSG_FILE)
    if msg_to_display == msg:
        pass
    else:
        msg_to_display = msg
        if msg_to_display == "[exit]":
            print "[%s] has disconnected.";
            raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
            exit(0)
        print "[%s]: %s\n" % (CLN, msg_to_display)
```

Note: These two scripts must be run on both PCs. One receives the message and displays them and the other sends them.

Here is my attempt at putting it together:

```
from sys import exit

LAN_NAME = "\\\\ONE-PC"
LAN_MSG_FILE = "%s\\Users\\Public\\me.txt" % LAN_NAME
CLN = "\\\\TWO-PC"
CLN_MSG_FILE = "%s\\Users\\Public\\me.txt" % CLN
TCHAT_VER = "1.0.2"

def fetch_data(src):
    file_ = open(src, 'r')
    file_data = file_.read()
    file_.close()
    return file_data

def send_data(src, data):
    file_ = open(src, 'w')
    file_.truncate()
    file_.write(data)
    file_.close()

def clean_cache(src):
    file_ = open(src, 'w')
    file_.truncate()
    file_.close()

print "TChat - Version %s" % TCHAT_VER
print "Copyright(c) 2013 - Ahnaf Tahmid"
print "--------------------------------"
print "\n"
print "To exit anytime, type in [exit]"
print "\n"

msg = raw_input("[You]: ")
msg_lan = " "

while msg != "[exit]":
    send_data(LAN_MSG_FILE, msg)
    print "\n"
    print "Fetching data.."
    msg_lan = fetch_data(CLN_MSG_FILE)
    while len(msg_lan) <= 1:
        msg_lan = fetch_data(CLN_MSG_FILE)
    clean_cache(CLN_MSG_FILE)
    print "\n"
    print "[Friend]: %s" % msg_lan
    print "\n"
    msg = raw_input("[You]: ")

print "\n"
print "Thanks for using TChat."
raw_input("Press ENTER to exit")
exit(0)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have already identified the basic problem: The need to run the sending and the receiving concurrently. You must delve into multi-threading.

The basic design pattern could be:

Create a thread for the receiving part with a flag for cancelling it. Loop infinitely doing the following: check to see if there is inbound data; if there is receive it and output it; sleep a timeout; break if the cancellation flag is set.

On the main thread, create your receiver and start it, then enter your input loop: If the user inputs a message, send it on the same thread. If the user types 'exit', set the cancellation flag on the receiver thread, wait for it and exit.

More or less:

```
class Receiver (Thread):
    def __init__ (self):
        super (Receiver, self).__init__ ()
        self.cancelled = False

    def run (self):
        while not self.cancelled:
            msg = nonBlockingReceive () # your non-blocking receive function
            if msg: print ('<< {}'.format (msg) )
            self.sleep (2)

receiver = Receiver ()
receiver.start ()
while True:
    msg = input ('>> ')
    if msg == 'exit':
        receiver.cancelled = True
        receiver.wait ()
        break
    sendData (msg) # your send function
```

(Just non-tested pseudo code)